# Apache ProxyPass exclude domain from virtual host

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, proxypass

I am performing some reverse proxies on my apache server, but I'm running into some problems.  I have a it proxying pages from another server which works fine with the following example:

```
ProxyPass /services/ http://www.server.com/services/
<Location /services/>
    ProxyPassReverse /services/
    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://example.server.com/services /services/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap /services/ /services/
</Location>
```

With this setup, pages from http://example.server.com/services are shown on http://www.server.com/services.  The issue is that my virtual hosts are now being affected.  So now pages from http://store.server.com/services are now pointing to the same proxied location, namely http://example.server.com/services.

Any idea on how to restrict the proxy so that proxied pages are only shown on www.server.com instead of all the virtual hosts like store.server.com?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you defining the ProxyPass and other proxy options within the VirtualHost? That should be enough to contain the reverse proxying within the VirtualHost.

Comment: If you have several domains on which rules are not the same build several name based virtulahosts and put configuration in the virtualhosts, not in global configuration

Comment: For the example given above, example.server.com is actually a separate machine running it's own instance of Apache.  www.server.com is the machine that also houses all the virtual hosts.  So I don't think I can contain the reverse proxying that way Ketola.